# Is using node.js is suitable for web GUI app and using same source for desktop app?

Tags: node.js

Im thinking about using node.js for web application , that is something like tomcat with servlents or Apache and php.
my questions are basic but fundamental:
 1. can i use node.js as web server? using jquery and all the server side stuff?
 2. i want to let the users to be able to use the application in offline mode , and let 
the user to download the web app as desktop app .

can node.js be good for this job ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Node.js is a platform for creating server-side and networking applications. You can use its HTTP and Socket support to create a web server.
   And yes, you can use client side libraries and frameworks like jQuery, Angular.js, Ember.js, etc etc. by using a Node.js REST API as backend (as a possible solution).
2. You can make desktop applications using:

> [Node-QT bindings](http://documentup.com/arturadib/node-qt)
>
> [Appjs](http://appjs.com/)